# Annual mean for Pandas dataset but not starting in January

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

In the dataframe below (small snippet show, actual dataframe spans from 2000 to 2014 in time), I want to compute the annual average but starting in September of one year and going till only May of next year.

```
Cnt Year    JD  Min_Temp
S   2000    1   277.139
S   2000    2   274.725
S   2001    1   270.945
S   2001    2   271.505
N   2000    1   257.709
N   2000    2   254.533
N   2000    3   258.472
N   2001    1   255.763
```

I can compute annual average (Jan - Dec) using this code:

```
df['Min_Temp'].groupby(df['YEAR']).mean()
```

How do I adapt this code to mean from Sept of first year to May of next year?

--EDIT: Based on comments below, you can assume that a MONTH column is also available, specifying the month for each row

Comment: What is Cnt? What is JD? [ask]

Comment: Sorry, JD is the julian day i.e. day 1 is jan 1st, dec 31st is day 365 (or 366). Cnt you can ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which column refers to month or if it is missing, but in the past I've used a quick and dirty method to assign custom seasons (interested if anyone has found more elegant route).

I've used Yahoo Finance data to demonstrate approach, unless one of your columns is Month?

*EDIT* Requires dataframe to be sorted by date ascending

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 31)
df = web.DataReader("F", 'yahoo', start, end)

#Ensure date sorted --required
df = df.sort_index()

#identify custom season and set months june-august to null
count = 0
season = 1
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if i.month in [9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5]:
        if count == 1:
            season += 1
        df.set_value(i,'season', season)
        count = 0
    else:
        count = 1
        df.set_value(i,'season',None)

#new data frame excluding months june-august
df_data = df[~df['season'].isnull()]
df_data['Adj Close'].groupby(df_data.season).mean()
```

Comment: In the case that you have 'Month' column you can substitute i.month for row['Month'].

Comment: In that case you can use the above fairly easily, just making sure that you are sorting on Date or Year/Month.